# Ionic 3 border radius of modal dialog not working in android

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I was trying to make the modal dialog with rounded corner.
I have researched this and made some changes on my code.
The code is as followings.

information.scss

```
 ion-modal.infomation ion-backdrop {
    visibility: visible !important;
    z-index:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
   ion-modal.infomation .modal-wrapper{
       top: 10%;
       width:80%;
       height: 50%;
       position:absolute;
       left: 10%;
       border-radius: 25px !important;
       background: transparent !important;
   }
   ion-page.modal {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
   page-infomation{
    .content{
        background-size: cover;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .logoimage{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
   }
```

information.html

```
<ion-content padding st #content>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <img src="assets/imgs/gameicons/correct.png" style="width:70px;height: 70px;">
    </div> 
    <div style="text-align: center;margin-top: 20px">
      <p 
      *ngIf="!type"
      style="color: #000000;
                font-size:18px;
                font-family: Tecnico !important;
                line-height: 1.0;
                ">
                {{m_content}}
      </p>
      <img [src]="logoImg" alt="" class="logoimage" *ngIf="type && logoImg != null"/>
      <p *ngIf = "type && logoImg == null">Not Available</p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

It worked perfectly in both of browser and ios version.
But in android version it showed the square not rounded.Please help me how can i fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will put the class outside the page tag, but be careful because it might affect the whole app modals if you didn't define a cssClass in the modalCtrl in TS file.

Import Modal Options like below:

```
import { ModalController, ModalOptions } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Inside the function that displays the modal:

```
openModal() {
let data = {any data you would like to pass};
let options: ModalOptions = { cssClass: 'your-class' } 
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(yourComponent, data, options); 
modal.present();
}
```

Then in your scss file:

```
ion-page{
/*some styles*/
}

.your-class .modal-wrapper{
border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Hi.Thank you for your answer.I tried but it still did not show the rounded corner.Could you provide working sample?Thanks.

Comment: it should work, i work with it in all of my projects, try to add cssClass to the modal options object

Comment: If possible,Could you attach sample code for it?I tried a lot but was wrong result.

Comment: Inside the function that displays the modal:
    let options: ModalOptions = {
      cssClass: 'your-class'
    }
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(yourComponent, options);
    modal.present();

Comment: i edited the answer, please follow the sample and tell me

Comment: sorry, i edited again now, it should now work for you